# How to disable Ajax cart sub total update functionality in WooCommerce cart page

Tags: ajax, woocommerce, cart, product-quantity, klarna

How we able to remove Ajax load functionality inside the Cart page when we update the quantity and press “Update Shopping Cart” button? During this process we want to refresh(Reload) the cart page.

Actually inside the cart page we have added Klarna Payment gateway option. So here Ajax load functionality not update the Klarna Payment gateway final total. Please review this -> https://nimb.ws/Pbtrzq screen shot.

So please inform me how to remove Ajax load functionality inside the Cart page “Update Shopping Cart” button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use the below snippet for that.

```
 jQuery( document.body ).on( 'updated_cart_totals', function () {
      location.reload( true );
 } );
```

Comment: I have integrated your code inside my website and issue fixed. Thank you :)